# How to boot Gigabyte GA-Z97X-UD3H motherboard with a 4 TB initialized WD HC310 HDD?

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, bios, gpt, cmos

I have a Gigabyte GA-Z97X-UD3H motherboard and I purchased a WD HC310 (0B35948 HUS726T4TALN6L4) HDD.

After I initialize the new HDD the PC cannot pass the POST (just freezes).

If we detach the new HDD, start the PC and then hotplug the new HDD, it's working fine. But it's not really convenient to uplug/replug the HDD each time the PC starts.

If we choose "IDE" or "RAID" mode of the SATA controller, PC starts OK, but the performance is worse.

How do we use the new HDD with 4TB NTFS volume in AHCI mode?

UPDATE1: found similar issue, not solved: https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/sata-hdd-freezes-bios-post-works-fine-hot-swap-after.2809733/

UPDATE2: neither MBR or GPT without any created volumes work, still freezes on POST. Only uninitialized disk can pass the POST.

UPDATE3: I've just tested this exact HDD with Gigabyte GA-B250M-D3H motherboard - though it's detected as 500 GB HDD in BIOS, it passes the POST and Windows sees it as 4 TB HDD perfectly.

UPDATE4: According to the answer by Mateusz, Gigabyte techsupport made a modified BIOS image, fixing the issue, here are 3 mirrors:

https://dropmefiles.com/DBOiF

https://www4.zippyshare.com/v/NdOaSaGS/file.html

https://gofile.io/d/0TWG0E

Comment: Did you set AHCI before you formatted it? If not, there's a registry hack you'll need to implement.

Comment: @spikey_richie this HDD is not supposed to be bootable, just for storage. It doesn't get to boot anything from any drive, because it just stucks in POST ("Press DEL to enter setup"). And yes, it was formatted in AHCI mode of course.

Comment: Is this HDD actually new or was it purchased used?  You shouldn't have to do anything except give it a file system.  You certainly shouldn't have to switch to IDE mode which would also disable ACHI for all your storage devices.  **Enabling IDE mode is not the correct solution, or even a solution, to the problem you describe**

Comment: @Ramhound the HDD is brand new. As I wrote in the post: all we did is create a ~4TB NTFS volume, that is all.
If we hotplug the HDD in AHCI or switch BIOS to "IDE" - we get all data. But, as you said, it's not a solution at all.

Comment: Do you have another system you can try the HDD in to make sure it's functional?

Comment: @Ramhound, again: if we hotplug it or use it in "IDE" mode - it's perfectly functional, except the inconvenience of hotpluging and low speed of "IDE" mode.

Comment: Is the motherboard BIOS up to date?

Comment: @gronostaj yes, tried F9 and F10b (latest beta).

Comment: @real_sm its gigabyte BIOS problem u can write to gigabyte customer care portal if motherboard is new and within warranty they will provided some update or solution

Comment: @Androidquery OK, done that in the first place, still no reply.

Comment: @real_sm  secondly I have seen some online questions in some question in AHCI mode Linux is is booted and windows was not able to boot  I think  gigabyte having problems  in detecting boot menu u can try with some grub boot menu for windows...still I will search for some solution and let u known If I find some tools and how to do it

Comment: @realSm yah gigabyte Customer care is slow in replying email you should call them and give a complain and don't forget to take ticket number call to their head office numbers

Comment: @Androidquery this new 4TB HDD is supposed to be used only for data, no OS installed.
If you find anything about that, please let me know, thank you!
I will wait for Gigabyte techsupport to reply in the Portal online.

Comment: @realsm are you using it as secondary HDD if yes then  remove it and. See that is first primary HDD is booting in AHCI mode without plugging 4TB HDD if its booting in AHCI mode then try to  remove first primary and plug this HDD on same slot and see if it boot s and say not a bootable device error come if yes then put the primary HDD on other slot and try to select to boot from it and let me know

Comment: @Androidquery primary HDD is booting in AHCI mode. PC freezes during POST only when this new 4TB HDD is attached to any slot, attached AND initialized (to MBR or GPT - doesn't matter, tried both). If 4TB HDD is attached and NOT initialized - POST is passed fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Z97X Gaming5 Rev 1.0 bios F7 here. Issues like described with hc310 6TB disk. 
The solution for me was to enable Intel Rapid Start Technology  and then it gave option under it to choose the controller to be used. I choose the other one that was available - "PCIE AHCI/NVME Controller" and system boots just fine. My disk with system is plextor ssd and HGST is the main storage.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please share the screenshot (photo) of your settings?

Comment: @real_sm done   :)

Comment: @MateuszSzyper - What is the "other one" exactly?  Edit your question to clarify your answer instead of submitting a comment.

Comment: @Mateusz, thank you, will try that.

Comment: @real_sm and what was the result?

Comment: @Mateusz sorry for the delay. Waited a looong time for the issue to resolve within techupport ticket, but that didn't happen. Yet.

I want to ask you, please, this is really serious. Please open a support ticket on the https://esupport.gigabyte.com with all the detailes and the issue that you can't boot with your HDD and default settings. This should speed up the process of resolving with a new BIOS image. Please do this, thank you very much!

Comment: @real_sm can you please link them to this issue? there is not much more i can do, i provided all the details.

Comment: @Mateusz I did, but that doesn't count. What counts is the number of claims. You just have to register and create a ticket in esupport.gigabyte.com - that will take you 15 minutes tops, but in return you will also have a BIOS fixing that and that will speed up the process for both of us. Please, please...

Comment: @Mateusz somehow BIOS reads the "Rapid Start store search type" option even when "Intel Rapid Start" is turned off:

1. Enable the "Intel Rapid Start Technology" and set "Rapid Start store search type" to "PCIE AHCI/NVME Controller".
2. Save and reboot.
3. Disable the "Intel Rapid Start Technology".
4. System boots OK.

So I'm marking this as an aswer, thank you! But please do create a ticket on  esupport.gigabyte.com, don't let it slide for them.

Comment: @Mateusz if you didn't open a ticket for them, here are links to the fixed BIOS image:

https://dropmefiles.com/DBOiF
https://www4.zippyshare.com/v/NdOaSaGS/file.html
https://gofile.io/d/0TWG0E

Answer (score 0):

REAL_SM

Try following steps

1. remove first primary HDD (which has OS) SATA cable from HDD

   ONLY plug this New 4TB HDD on same slot same sata cable  (without connecting primary HDD) and see if it boot in AHCI mode  (not hand on POST)

   "then error will come not a bootable device"
2. if error comes and it works independently on AHCI mode  then it confirmed that there is no problem with HDD  and it is  working with AHCI independently

if it does not work independently  it means either motherboard dont support 4tb hdd in AHCI or not formatted in proper files system ( for motherboard update BIOS or controllers or get some PCIE to sata card controller which can support)

3. if 4tb hdd booted in AHCI mode independently it worked then keep it on the same slot and  try to  put the primary HDD (in which OS is there)  on other slots and try to select first boot device to  boot from  primary one (boot OS) it from BIOS  and see if other hdd works on other slot in AHCI mode

if yes then you got it  and if no then means only 1 slot is working in AHCI mode

4. try one by one to try on all sata slots the other HDD may be it worked with any other slot
5. if not work then Try to update motherboard BIOS or driver  for sata controllers

let me know and update if  what worked for you and not
and whats the result

I m little busy in solving some problems  i cant find in detail issue but still giving  some links to you read and find if any one work for you

if not then try to find solutions in following links if any of them work

**According to Referred from thanks to user Ruslan Makrenko in Super user forum website says**

[Convert Secondary Harddrive to AHCI from IDE](https://superuser.com/questions/1087190/convert-secondary-harddrive-to-ahci-from-ide)

> So don't worry, Install your newest SSD or HDD using AHCI mode and just plug in your oldest drive - it will work perfectly without any flaws.
>
> In case if you wanna boot old system (windows or linux) from old drive- change mode to IDE in bios.
>
> And, maybe we should generalize it not only for Windows 10, but from Windows 7 (XP has deprecated support of AHCI and TRIM, for example)
>
> To prove my words I've googled a bit and found an perfect answer: http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-2668430/ahci-ide-mix.html
>
> BTW, it is not the first install that I perform like thread starter asked. There are at least 4 machines working from 2007 to right now  2016 and them operating brilliant using so called 'Mixed' modes AHCI/IDE.

**According to Referred from thanks to user oinkypig in tomshardware forum website says**

https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/computer-wont-recognize-secondary-hdd-in-ahci-mode.1402326/

> the RAID tool config, even when no raid drives are used, is only in place as a bootup utility tool for raid detection upon setup. Its independent of either drives in this case. Dont place the SSD in AHCI mode, whenever i do the same i always get huge bootup slowdowns and HDD reading faults on my asus p6t v2. Any other bootup configuration should work fine otherwise as in my case. I set mine to enhanced mode or IDE mode. Always unless you do run a raid setup turn off the raid bootup all together, if anything thats only causing slowdowns during bootup. Although it doesnt hurt you could leave the RAID drivers active and disable the boot rom from bios.

https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/solved-pc-hangs-at-auto-detect-ahci-drive-help.668687/

https://forums.guru3d.com/threads/guide-enabling-ahci-mode-after-windows-7-installation.313676/

https://support.hp.com/in-en/document/c02961221

Comment: SSD (OS) connected to port 0, HDD (storage) connected to port 1

1. Removed cable from SSD - freeze on POST
2. no error, freeze on POST
3-4. tried all the ports with HDD - freeze on POST
5. Tried BIOS F9, F10b, F10c, tried updating RST roms in BIOS to version 14 - freeze on POST.

Solutions don't work because OS boots after POST, which I cannot pass in AHCI mode.

Comment: @REAL_SM bro  u did wrong.... Disconnect SSD from SATA0 port  COMPLETELY  AND FORGET ....AND CONNECT HDD ON PORT 0    in AHCI mode with same cable of and see if your POST freezes and crooses it not. as HDD don't have booting files it will give errors and not boot but it should cross POST and not freeze

Comment: what do you mean wrong? You wrote "remove first primary HDD (which has OS) SATA cable from HDD" - I did that. Disconnected completely, even power cable.

"CONNECT HDD ON PORT 0 in AHCI mode with same cable" - I wrote: "3-4. tried all the ports with HDD", that means including port 0, I tried the same cable that SSD connected, also I tried brand new cable.

Comment: @REAL_sm if i am not wrong that you disconnected the SATA completely and tried 4TB HDD and selected AHCI mode in all ports ie. 0,1,2,3,4.... and still POST was freezing .

Comment: this is exactly what I did. No other SATA devices, only 4TB HDD, port 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 - freeze on POST in AHCI mode.

Comment: @Real_sm okay then i think as per my experience that  "if it does not work independently it means either motherboard dont support 4tb hdd" or  particular model or HDD have some configuration not formatted in proper file system that supports AHCI mode... let me check your motherboard and HDD model configs details if any  issue as such on net with the same models

Comment: just in case: this same HDD lets the system pass the POST when in IDE or RAID mode. Also I can access this 4 TB HDD if I try to boot OS (from any other drive, USB flash drive etc) with disconnected HDD and connect it after POST (hotplug).

Comment: @ REAL_SM  i will get in touch soon with proper update it will take some time collecting informations and finding the solution let u know bro soon

Comment: I've just tested this exact HDD with GA-B250M-D3H - though it's detected as 500 GB HDD in BIOS, it passes the POST and Windows sees it as 4 TB HDD perfectly.

Comment: @ Real_Sm But it detects 500GB in BIOS and is it working in AHCI mode in  GA-B250M-D3H

Comment: @ REAL_SM do tell me please Do please tell me whats Bootable  SSD size (its 1tb 2tb or 4tb) and whats the partition sizes and MBR/GPT you are using and working fine in AHCI mode Secondly do tell me if you are using single 4tb partitions in 4TB hdd in MBR/GPT  or multiple partitions with what size of partition table

Comment: @ Androidquery I do not own the GA-B250M-D3H board, so I can test only with GA-Z97X-UD3H now. Yes, GA-B250M-D3H detected 4 TB HDD as 500 GB, but it's only in BIOS and it doesn't matter to me unless it lets pass POST and detects as 4 TB in Windows. But I want to avoid unnecessary upgrade and stay with GA-Z97X-UD3H.

Comment: Bootable SSD is 180 GB, it has 1 full-size partition and some small system partitions. Also before I had 1TB drive with 1 full-size 1 TB partition. All GPT, of course, because of UEFI.
With 4 TB HDD it doesn't matter - MBR or GPT, has partitions and what size are they. If it's just initialized - it won't pass POST.

Comment: @real_sm bro sorry updated my new answer  before  seeing your latest comments and updates my question for latest comment that you checked hdd on different motherboard GA-B250M-D3H But it detects 500GB in BIOS and IS IT WORKING in AHCI mode in GA-B250M-D3H  or in IDE or RAID Mode

Comment: with GA-B250M-D3H it passes POST in AHCI mode perfectly. Didn't even test in IDE or RAID mode.

Comment: @real_sm bro as second comment "With 4TBit doesn't matter - MBR or GPT, ....what size are they...." what i readed in many sites and links and videos you can see  in my new answers reference links provided that 2TB+ HDD  will not work or detected in BIOS if  MBR it works only  in GPT with partitions and if it detects then it may give problem with many boards BIOS AHCI all compatibility of controllers issues except you can use as  hotplug IDE or  connect externally through sata or esata ..rest may be i am wrong i have to see details i havent yet practiclly tried 4tb i used upto 2tb till now

Comment: @Real_SM with as per your comment " GA-B250M-D3H it passes POST in AHCI mode perfectly. Didn't even test in IDE or RAID mode" then its quite obvious that your motherboard GA-Z97X-UD3H BIOS is culprit and it not supporting with 4TB AHCI mode but on finding ur solution i have founded that it not only your board its quiet familar problem with many users in many boards may be GPT partitions filesystem bootloader or BIOS compatibilty issue with certain BIOS may be find some more technical papers or research on it tommorw

Answer (score 0):

**updating with new answer on continuation with the previous answer as on getting clarity update  through comments discussions and R & D and findings**

@ REAL_SM Bro a request from you

1. Do please tell me whats Bootable  SSD size (its 1tb 2tb or 4tb) and whats the partition sizes and MBR/GPT you are using and working fine in AHCI mode
2. Secondly do tell me if you are using single 4tb partitions in 4TB hdd in MBR/GPT  or multiple partitions with what size of partition table

**as you must know that MBR dont supports hdd more than 2tb and  for that you have to use GPT partitions and  i am assuming that you must be using GPT partitions in your 4tb HDD if not then see videos link how to**

Real_Sm bro as there are **many articles regarding** with problem of same type and in many other boards 4tb hdd is also not detected as it should be used in GPT partitions then MBR one secondly some BIOS if you are using GPT partitions  **with motherboards** and i think the problem  is with  **GA-Z97X-UD3H motherboard** **BIOS BUG** and gigabyte has not resolved it in updates may be compatibility issues for  4TB HDD

As Per my experience and knowledge and point of view

**So my Suggestions and Advice**

which you have to try  and depends on which one works 
with your motherboard

1. Either be **satisfied** and keep you HDD in **IDE or RAID mode hotplug mode** and work  and **compromise with  speed**
2. Either Buy **new Motherboard** ( BEFORE CONFIRMING THAT new MOTHERBOARD SUPPORTS GPT 4TB HDD and for this small issue  i will suggest NOT to make any expenditure)

   **if your 4tb hdd is already  partitioned and 
       MAINLY GPT partitions  with 1st primary 
       partition then skip below if not then try**

   **if its not GPT partitions**  then try to 
         **convert MBR to GPT** 
         (BEWARE 5% to 10% RISK OF DATA LOSS 
          **take backups before converting**) by 
         seeing following links without  data loss
         and check test  if  POST freeze or not after 
         conversions without connecting any other
         SATA drives in any slot

https://www.diskpart.com/gpt-mbr/convert-mbr-to-gpt-without-data-loss.html

https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmagic/will-converting-mbr-to-gpt-erase-all-the-disk-partitions.html

https://www.easeus.com/partition-manager-software/convert-mbr-to-gpt-gpt-to-mbr-using-cmd-without-losing-data.html

https://www.thewindowsclub.com/convert-mbr-to-gpt-disk

**or try following  steps one by one at your wish and risk**

3. if your **4TB HDD have no data** then **zero fill or  delete all partitons** and **make it a RAW HDD** without any partition (through WD official  Data Lifeguard Diagnostics for Windows link provided)

   https://support-en.wd.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/10850
4. Then put the **4TB hdd  RAW HDD** (on all SATA slots 0,1,2,3,4..) as previously done indvidually without connecting **any other SATA drives** if it still freezes POST or not

Dont worry if it POST freezes or not Freezes as full 4TB still may not be detected by BIOS then try following

5. then **Create small 2-3 small partitions** in **4TB GPT HDD partitions** by diskpart windows 10 or  windows setup cd or either by following tools

   1. **Diskpart of windows 10**
      or **AOMEI Partition Assistant Standard**

   https://www.diskpart.com/diskpart/convert-gpt-4125.html

   2. **EaseUS Partition Master**

https://www.easeus.com/partition-master/partition-gpt-disk.html

3. **MiniTool Partition Wizard 11.6**

https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmagic/will-converting-mbr-to-gpt-erase-all-the-disk-partitions.html

**My IDEA advice suggestion  for GPT partition to try which one can work**

**One of the either partition size you wish and comforts suits to you  as per my advice i m suggesting as per my view point**

```
A) First Primary Active    10GB-20 GB Fat32 
   (which you can use as Virtual RAM or SWAP)
   format in FAT32 file system and make it
   bootable with system  files for testing

  Second Secondary Partition OF  380TB

  Third logical Partition   180TB  EXFAT
           format in EXFAT file system 
  Fourth logical  Partition   180TBGB  EXFAT
         format in EXFAT file system
```

B)  Then again put the **4TB hdd with 20GB and logical partitions of 180TB** each  (on **all SATA slots 0,1,2,3,4.**.) as previously done individually without connecting any other drives on SATA port if it still frezees POST or not  to test and check if this partitions is supportable or not

if it worked and you are comfortable with  partitions then **skip other steps and  now  try to put SSD** and boot and may all works fine if not then try a**nother partition with size**  and other file systems like  EXT4

```
   C)  First Primary Active        2TB   EXFAT 
           format in EXFAT file system 
       Second primary/logical      2TB   EXFAT
               format in EXFAT file system
```

D)  Then again put the **4TB hdd with two  2TB  primary and secondary 2TB partitions** (on all SATA slots 0,1,2,3,4..) as previously done individually without connecting **any other SATA drives** if it still freezes POST or not  to test and check if this partitions is supportable or not

**the main aim of above trials is to check which GPT partitions   or partition table your mother Board  supports  and POST dont freezes on**

6. another option may be  trying  **different boot menus or file systems** like of linux like GRUB  may they can work

**see foolowing link of  site and videos  for reference and other  problems**

https://www.win-raid.com/t6186f16-Gigabyte-GA-Z-X-UD-H-cannot-boot-in-AHCI-mode-if-HDD-initialized-in-GPT-or-MBR-could-BIOS-mod-help.html

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FFnKXDPE_Ls&t=11s

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g2iFj56NDg8

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e-7x-VG7ABc

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=amSjHDDn-J0

I  **Answered and concluded** after looking the  **following links and findings** and **sharing with u** for **your reference** and if u like to see the views of other website and people with same and other motherboards

REAL_Sm bro for  you i have tried to google search and find solution and finded  many things and  sharing with you all with my views and solutions  which you have to try which you have not tried yet or  suits you it upto you

**My findings**

1. As the **link provided** by you and googled by me Same Mother board but different hdd of segate problem in the toms hardware link

https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/sata-hdd-freezes-bios-post-works-fine-hot-swap-after.2809733/

**User olxiasi  comments says**

> The BIOS will not boot with an exFat partition larger than 2TB if this partition was created in Windows (ver 7) or Mac OS (ver 10.8.5).
>
> I tried 2Tb + 2Tb (exFat) partitions in Mac OS. Boots Fine.
>
> SO, I will make the partition EXT4 and just use it this way and forgo exFat.

**My views and comments on the link**

1. The the solution and problem detected by the user was that it created a **2TB EXFAT partition** and used it.
2. It means that BIOS is not detecting MBR GPT  partition **size of  4Tb second** file system its supporting 2TB partition in  Linux but not in windows
3. it means its not detecting **MBR  and partitions** of or single  4TB partition

My conclusion for your problem as per the link:-

**As Described detailed in detail above steps also**

1. As "olxiasi"  tried Try creating EXFAT you to try 3 senarios which suits and works for you
2. 10GB -20GB  first active primary partition  (which you can use as Virtual RAM or some other drive) of FAT32 and rest with  EXFAT file system  (as some BIOS or post dont detect or hangs over in detecting large 1st Active bootable partition size)
         or
3. 2TB first active primary  partion of EXFAt and another win 2 TB exfat see if it works with windows

In **continuation of   the above link** there is another link  you can see for same board there **many solutions** are  there which you can read answers see if it matches in your case

https://www.win-raid.com/t6186f16-Gigabyte-GA-Z-X-UD-H-cannot-boot-in-AHCI-mode-if-HDD-initialized-in-GPT-or-MBR-could-BIOS-mod-help.html

2. **In the manual of Gigabyte GA-Z97X-UD3H motherboard**

http://download.gigabyte.us/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_ga-z97x-ud3h_v1.1_e.pdf

**Page no. 25 topic  SATA3 0/1/2/3/4/5 (SATA 6Gb/s Connectors) says**

> • **M.2, SATA Express,** and SATA3 4/5 connectors can only be used one at a time. The SATA3 4/5 connectors will become unavailable when an M.2 SSD is installed.

**My views and comments**

it means you are using SSD in M2 Slot in  your motherboard then SATA3 4 and 5 connector will not work i think you are using  **SSD on SATA port not on M2 port**

**page no. 55  topic SATA Mode Selection  says**

> AHCI Configures the SATA controllers to AHCI mode. Advanced Host  Controller Interface (AHCI) is an interface specification that allows the storage driver to enable advanced Serial ATA features such as Native Command Queuing and hot plug. (Default)

**NO views and comments just for your reference on this finding**

**Page No. 61 topic "Configuring SATA Hard Drive(s)" says**

> D. Install the SATA RAID/AHCI driver and operating system (Note 2)

**My views and comments on finding**

this means that **SATA RAID/ AHCI driver is available to install on OS** for configurations let me find it for you

**page number 61 to page 66  steps for configuring SATA Controller in BIOS**

**My views and comments**

there **are steps from  step 1 to step 5** given check all steps carefully if you missed or followed it or not

**page number 73  on topic 3-2 Installing the SATA RAID/AHCI Driver and Operating System  part A Installing the Operating System**

> we **recommend** that you install all required drivers from the **motherboard driver disk** using "Xpress Install" to ensure system performance and compatibility

**My views and comments**

Means in windows 7 drivers are there but should install Motherboard driver disk using  XPress install or from its websites link

> To install Windows 8.1/8, refer to the steps below:

**My views and comments**

if you are using windows 7 /8/10 see if some steps work for you and find  **drivers of  disk on motherboard** site or xpress Install of cd if u can find any

**page number 86 TOpic 5-2-3 EZ Setup and subtopic  Disk Mode Switch says**

> **Disk Mode Switch** allows you to switch the operating mode for your hard drive even after it's been installed with an operating system. Supported operating modes include IDE, AHCI, and RAID. You can select a disk mode and restart your computer after the selection. • Native UEFI mode is not supported. • Be sure to reinstall the Intel® Rapid Storage Technology utility after you switch the disk mode.

**My views and comments**

there any many tools and softwares available of gigabyte to configure AHCI RAID may it  automattically work

1. First tool **Disk Mode Switch**
2. Second tool  **EZ Setup**

**page number 86 TOpic 5-2-3 EZ Setup and subtopic  Disk Mode Switch says**

> at last to sum up  finded compiled may some option work it for you and may god help you to sort your problem do tell me if any one works best of luck may information useful for you or for your knowledge or future reference

Comment: 1. Bootable SSD size - 180 GB whole disk, 1 full-size NTFS GPT partition and 3 more small system partitions.
2. First of all immediately after unboxing I initialized the new HDD in GPT and created a full-size partition. After these days I see that it doesn't matter if I initialize HDD in GPT or MBR, and it doesn't matter if I create any partitions at all - just initialization leads to freeze during POST.

Comment: 3-4. If the drive is RAW (unitialized) - it lets the POST pass in AHCI mode.
5. Tried creating small GPT partitions, small MBR partition, tried just initialization - the same result: freeze during post.
Thank you for all the links (one of them is my post from another forum). I don't need exFAT, though it too results in freeze during post. Thanks for the other info, I had read everything, as you may see almost everything can be applied when the OS is booted, but there's nothing about freeze during POST. Sorry.

Comment: @real_sm bro as per yout comment " If the drive is RAW (unitialized) - it lets the POST pass in AHCI mode"....does it reflects 4TB in your BIOS of motherboard Gigabyte GA-Z97X-UD3H  when its unitilized how much GB or TB it reflects in BIOS

Comment: when disk is RAW it is shown as 4000GB HDD in BIOS of GA-Z97X-UD3H
If it's initialized - I obviously cannot enter BIOS setup because of freeze during POST (and you can enter setup only after POST).

Comment: @real_sm bro i have an idea if your HDD as it is reflected and detected in BIOS full 4000GB (when 4TB is unitialised) then it means BIOS is detecting on unitlialized disk and it POST (is going in some un ended looping) when u initialize it  or partition file system or GPT it freezes.it means that POST or BIOS cant read after initializing of HDD in AHCI mode. But u tried with partitioning also in GPT and MBR did you tried with creating only 1  100GB -500GB partition and hiding rest part of HDD just keep 500GB HDD after intializing then 4000TB but think of no use at last we have to use 4000GB

Comment: @real_Sm then i think have an idea that u can find a 3rd party SATA controller card like PCIE to SATA or PCIE to ESATA converters but dont know about AHCI (from friend technician or market)  see this one writting about 6GBps and AHCI 4 ports https://www.startech.com/Cards-Adapters/HDD-Controllers/SATA-Cards/4-Port-PCI-Express-SATA-6Gbps-RAID-Controller-Card~PEXSAT34RH i will work i know

Comment: Please stop posting multiple answer to questions. You can edit the original answer if you have updates or more information.

Answer (score 0):

**NEW ANSWER FOR NEW AND FINAL UPDATE IN CONTINUATION AFTER YOUR TESTING OF ABOVE ANSWERS COMMENTS AND DISCUSSIONS WITH REAL_SM (the questioner)**

Real_SM

i have checked configurations of your motherboard and founded its chipset details and  its datasheet and founded that you motherboard **GA-Z97X-UD3H** (is intel Z97 chipset that is family of   9 series chipset)  does not support the **AHCI mode directly** it  is configured through many **ELECTRONICS REGISTARS AND CHI**P programming which is done generally by **Motherboard Manufacturer** as manufacturers associate or combine other chips(as found marvell drivers may be marvell chipset to associated with it) to program it and for that if you want then directly contact Gigabyte Service Center Engineer  or write to in gigabyte forum and ask for Support  if they can suggest you.

https://www.gigabyte.com/Support

https://www.gigabyte.com/Support/Motherboard

https://forum.gigabyte.us/thread/904/samsung-960-evo-recognized-bios

and in  **motherboard GA-B250M-D3H** (Intel® B250 Express Chipset which is of family 200 series chipset)  it is **directly specified** that it supports **supporting AHCi 1.3 and AHCi 1.3.1** mode

So my recommendation and solution is to go for **3rd Party  Sata controller** or **PCIE to Sata3 ESATA cards** which is tested benchmarked  and support **4tb to 6tb HDD in AHCI mode** and chipset supports 4tb but speed  performance and those cards will support in  your Motherboard or not its matter of **R&D and testing** as i think it should work or u can again email or write to in gigabyte forum and ask In Gigabyte  Support  if they can suggest you which card will work. .

for your reference sharing and giving you links of such **PCIE to sata3 converter** cards for your reference

https://www.startech.com/Cards-Adapters/HDD-Controllers/SATA-Cards/4-Port-PCI-Express-SATA-6Gbps-RAID-Controller-Card~PEXSAT34RH

**this card  describes in specification of support to 4tb AhCI mode**

there are **many other cards** but without  **4tb AHCi  details**  or  specification so  i am not sharing links you can search yourself.

I m sharing below the links for your reference for  data sheets i have finded and links through which i came into conclusions for your reference

**datasheet of  Intel Z97 is Intel 9 Series chipset says**

https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/datasheets/9-series-chipset-pch-datasheet.pdf

> In datasheet could not found direct AHCI support that  9 series chipsets does not support the AHCI mode directly it  is configured through many REGISTER AND CHIP programming which is done generally by Motherboard Manufacturer as it associate or combine other chips to prograam it.

**datasheet of  Intel B250 is intel 200 series chipset  says**

https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/datasheets/200-series-chipset-pch-datasheet-vol-1.pdf

**page no. 232  Topic SATA Feature Support says**

> The PCH SATA controller is capable of supporting all AHCI 1.3 and AHCI 1.3.1, refer to the Intel web site on Advanced Host Controller Interface Specification for current specification status: http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/io/serial-ata/ahci.html.

**Comparison of chipset features**

Intel® B250 Express Chipset
Intel® Z97 Express Chipset

**https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/compare.html?productIds=98086,82012**

**GA-B250M-D3H (rev. 1.0)  Intel® B250 Express Chipset**

https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-B250M-D3H-rev-10/sp#sp

**Storage Interface**

Chipset:
1 x M.2 PCIe connector
(Socket 3, M key, type 2242/2260/2280 SATA & PCIe SSD support)
1 x SATA Express connector
6 x SATA 6Gb/s connectors
(M.2, SATA Express, and SATA3 4/5 connectors can only be used one at a time. The SATA3 4/5 connectors will become unavailable when an M.2 SSD is installed.)
Support for RAID 0, RAID 1, RAID 5, and RAID 10

**GA-Z97X-UD3H (rev. 1.0)  Intel® Z97 Express Chipset**

https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-Z97X-UD3H-rev-10/sp#sp

**Storage Interface**

Chipset:
1 x M.2 connector (Socket 3, M key, type 2242/2260/2280/22110 SATA and PCIe x4/x2 SSD support)
1 x SATA Express connector
* The SATA Express connector is not compatible with regular SATA devices.
6 x SATA 6Gb/s connectors
* Refer to "1-7 Internal Connectors," for the installation notices for the M.2 and SATA connectors.

Comment: Please stop posting multiple answer to questions. You can edit the original answer if you have updates or more information.

Comment: @DavidPostil OK will not post multiple answers

Answer (score 0):

**DON'T TRY THAT IF YOU HAVE ANY CRITICAL DATA ON THE HDD! ALWAYS MAKE A COPY OF THE DATA!**

After initialization (and any further creation of volumes, copying files etc), but BEFORE the reboot, open a hex editor, in the editor - disk and delete (fill with "00") from offset 0x1000 to 0x1060. Save, reboot.

After reboot this data is recreated, but it doesn't make the POST of Gigabyte GA-Z97X-UD3H freeze.

**DON'T TRY THAT IF YOU HAVE ANY CRITICAL DATA ON THE HDD! ALWAYS MAKE A COPY OF THE DATA!**

P.S. Can anyone, please, explain, what is this at offset 0x1000-0x1060? How could it freeze POST in "BEFORE" state? What happens after I delete it and reboot? Why is it recreated differently (and doesn't freeze POST)?

[image: culprit]